# How to compare NoneType with Float on Python

Tags: python-3.x, int, nonetype

I'm writing a code in Python 3 to show the max and min value between some numbers. And it's giving an error.

```
sml_value = None
largest_value = None

while True:
    line = input('Enter a number: ')
    if line == 'done':
        break
    try:
        fl = float(line)
    except:
        print('Invalid input')
        continue
    if line < sml_value:
        sml_value = line
    elif line > largest_value:
        largest_value = line
print(sml_value, largest_value)
```

Output:

```
Enter a number: 5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exercise5.2.py", line 13, in <module>
    if line < sml_value:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'NoneType'
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be comparing `fl`, not `line`? And you need to specifically consider the case that `sml_value` or `largest_value` `is None`, because that's what you initially set them to.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I'll try that

Comment: Would the conditional statement be:     if sml_value is None:
        sml_value = fl
    elif largest_value is None:
        largest_value = fl
    elif sml_value < fl:
        sml_value = fl
    elif largest_value > fl:
        largest_value = fl

Comment: Probably not `elif`, otherwise you only set one of them for the first non-`None` value.

Answer (score 0):

```
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done" :
        break
    try :
        num = float(num)
    except :
        print('Invalid Input')
        continue
    if largest is None or num > largest:
        largest = num
    elif smallest is None or num < smallest:
        smallest = num
print("Maximum is", int(largest))
print("Minimum is", int(smallest))
```

Comment: As you have kindly written up someone else's comments into an answer, it would be a much better answer if you could [edit] your answer and highlight what you have done in the body of the answer so that other people can learn from it.